# Deleting Multiple Local Users

Tags: powershell

This is my first post in the community even though I was reading it for many years. The truth is that I just started scripting so I am very new to it. So I am trying to make a script that searches for a few specific local users and deletes them if it finds them.

```
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$USERNAME = "test1"

$ObjLocalUser = $null

try {
    Write-Verbose "Searching for $($USERNAME) in LocalUser DataBase"
    $ObjLocalUser = Get-LocalUser $USERNAME
    Write-Verbose "User $($USERNAME) was found"
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UserNotFoundException] {
    "User $($USERNAME) not was found" | Write-Warning
}
catch {
    "An unspecifed error occured" | Write-Error
    Exit # Stop Powershell! 
}

if ($ObjLocalUser) {
    Write-Verbose "Deleting User $($USERNAME)" #(Example)
    
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$op = Get-LocalUser | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $USERNAME}
if ($op)
 {
  Remove-LocalUser ($op) | Out-Null
 }
}
```

This is what I have up to now. It seems to work good with one username but when I try to add more than one usernames in the variable it doesn't work. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to my question and it was pretty simple. That's the final code.

```
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$USERNAMES = @("test1","test2","test3","test14","testpass")
foreach ($username in $USERNAMES) {

$ObjLocalUser = $null

try {
    Write-Verbose "Searching for $($username) in LocalUser DataBase"
    $ObjLocalUser = Get-LocalUser $username
    Write-Verbose "User $($username) was found"
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UserNotFoundException] {
    "User $($username) was not found" | Write-Warning
}
catch {
    "An unspecifed error occured" | Write-Error
    Exit # Stop Powershell! 
}

if ($ObjLocalUser) {
    Write-Verbose "Deleting User $($username)" #(Example)
    
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$op = Get-LocalUser | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $username}
if ($op)
 {
  Remove-LocalUser ($op) | Out-Null
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The unfortunate thing is that after all that I can't use it cause I dont need to remove local users but admin accounts from Group "Administrator".

Comment: How about cleaning the group with a GPO? It is quite simple and a way that works. Goto "How to Remove users From The local admin group with group policy" on the page https://activedirectorypro.com/remove-local-admin-rights-using-group-policy/    --- You just change the member of the group, but let the users enabled. if you wish to disable users it is almost the same way. If it is this something you need some help, just ask.